# Bash: Execute command from variable without eval

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I have a problem with a script which should execute a `curl` command composed from the given arguments. It works if I use `eval` in the subshell, however, I would like to avoid that as it seems to be bad style according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' -X POST -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -H \"Accept:application/json\" https://www.example.com/login -d '{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}'"
echo $(eval $COMMAND)
```

With eval, I get 201 or 401 depending on the validity of the given credentials as expected. If I remove eval and use `echo $($COMMAND)` I get 400 which indicates a wrongly constructed data parameter.

Can someone explain to me, how I have to construct the command such that I can directly pass it to a subshell?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pierre.

After some more attempts of trial and error about where to place which kind of quotes I finally got this working:

```
$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" https://example.com/login -d "{\"username\":"\"$1\"",\"password\":"\"$2\""}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use backticks or nesting to avoid using eval.

**Backticks**

```
$ var=\`curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' -X POST -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -H \"Accept:application/json\" https://www.example.com/login -d '{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}'"\`
```

**Nesting**

```
$ var = $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' -X POST -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -H \"Accept:application/json\" https://www.example.com/login -d '{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}'")
```

Nesting is supported on the vast majority of shells and more readable than backticks.

Comment: Although since you are explicitly using bash, I would suggest you replace the backticks with nest-friendly `var=$( curl ... )`

Comment: Right. Answer updated !